# Password field in editing

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

When I want edit my user I have a problem with the password field. When I select my user to edit I can edit first name, last name and password but I can edit only first name and leave the password field unchanged. When I click edit start I receive an error:

```
The password field is empty.
```

My password field:

```
<p:password id="password" value="#{userMB.user.password}" label="#{msg.password}" required="true">
    <f:validator validatorId="passwordValidator2" />   
    <p:ajax update="msgPassword" event="keyup" /> 
</p:password>
```

Why?

When I changed the `<p:password>` with `<h:inputText>` it worked fine. But I see password my user...
Why `<p:password>` does not read the initial value of `userMB.user.password`?

Comment: Are you talking about Primefaces <p:password />?

Comment: post your validator. Is it always saying it's empty after typing in a character ?

Comment: Yes. Primefaces. What validator? This field should already be filled in at the start editing like any other field first name and last name.

Comment: Wait what ? Are you saying you already have a user  in your db and when you try to edit him his password is not showing up in the password field  but it's showing up when you use an input text ? If that's the case try to add redisplay = "true" to password. Let me know if that works

Comment: Also when I said validator I meant the code you are using for `passwordValidator2`

Comment: Big thanks. Redisplay is work.

Comment: Ok, I'll add it as an answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `redisplay = "true"` to your `password` component

```
<p:password id="password" value="#{userMB.user.password}" label="#{msg.password}" required="true" redisplay = "true">
```